# Why does division give you slope?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If I have a vector extending from the origin, why would its slope be given by the quotient of its y and x components? How does dividing a vertical guy and a horizontal guy give you the diagonal guy?

edit:
Maybe I should have phrased it like "why does the algebraic operation of taking the quotient of two scalars give you the geometric interpretation of the slope"

Comment: What do you mean by slope, if not the ratio of vertical change and horizontal change? And slope is not exactly the "diagonal guy".

Comment: The very definition of slope is the ratio of the change in vertical height to the change in the horizontal length

Comment: Rise over run: $m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Comment: Consider the following: suppose on one side of the roof, the roof rises 2 ft for every horizontal foot, and on the other side rises 3 feet for every horizontal foot. If a rooster lays an egg at the apex of the roof, which side would it fall on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't exactly clear.  But, let me provide an answer for the simple question of where the "slope" of a line comes from.

The equation of a line is given

$$y = mx + b$$

and let's say we have two points on that line $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ which sets up the system of equations

$$ y_1 = mx_1 + b \\ y_2 = mx_2 + b$$

where we have two equations and two unknowns.

The term $m$ can be found by solving the system of equations to obtain

$$ m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} $$

which can be defined more generically as

$$ m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}}$$

where $m$ is defined as the slope of the line.

Answer (score 0):

$$Slope=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$
So ,
$$Slope=\frac{y-0}{x-0}$$
$$Slope=\frac{y}{x}$$